# xml php viewing

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am trying to practice making making some xml and also a parser for xml in php.

Currently if I have an xml file, I have to open it in notepad to see all the "tags" for it.  This isn't very good and their is no indenting or spacing correctly so I have to search through carefully.

Is there something way to display the xml in the indented style so I can easily see what is the parent and what is the child?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best XML editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073/what-is-the-best-xml-editor)

Comment: Not really.  I want a viewer not necessarily an editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Notepad++ has some plugin that makes your XML pretty. Also opening it in a browser like Firefox or Internet explorer will show you the XML with better markup. If you dont see anything use view source!

There are also some online solutions, just google `XML Pretty` or `XML tidy`. For example: http://tools.decisionsoft.com/xmlpp.html